# Splitting list into n-tuples

Tags: haskell

How can I split a list into list of tuples/lists of specified length?
splitBy :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]

splitBy 2 "asdfgh" should return ["as", "df", "gh"]

Comment: Nitpicking: Splitting into n-tuples (where n is not constant for a function) isn't possible, and you don't really ask for it either - you want sublists of length n.

Comment: `takeWhile (not.null) . unfoldr (Just . splitAt n)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`splitEvery`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/split/0.1.4/doc/html/Data-List-Split.html) usually gets the nod for this job.

Comment: This module Data.List.Split must be new, right? I don't have it on my system, nor does it turn up on Hoogle…

Comment: Version 0.1 was uploaded Sun Dec 21 19:02:04 UTC 2008 according to hackage. I don't think Hoogle indexes much of hackage, but Hayoo! finds it.

Comment: `splitEvery` is now called `chunksOf`

Answer (score 3):

Searching [Hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/) for `Int -> [a] -> [[a]]` yields [`chunksOf`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/text/latest/doc/html/Data-Text.html#v%3achunksOf), which may be of use.

Answer (score 2):

One way of doing it:

```
splitBy :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
splitBy _ [] = []
splitBy n xs = take n xs : splitBy n (drop n xs)
```

Another way of doing it:

```
splitBy' :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
splitBy' _ [] = []
splitBy' n xs = fst split : splitBy' n (snd split)
                where split = splitAt n xs
```

Comment: `([x] ++)` is `(x :)` and function application has highest precendence, so the last line can be written as `splitBy n xs = take n xs : splitBy n (drop n xs)`.

Comment: @delnan: thanks! this shows that I'm learning Haskell ... but your comments help me :)