# Grouping a list into lists of n elements in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell

Is there an operation on lists in library that makes groups of n elements? For example: n=3

```
groupInto 3 [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
```

If not, how do I do it?

Comment: If such a function existed, its type would be `Int -> [a] -> [[a]]` so you can Hoogle that. Not seeing anything though: http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=Int%20-%3E%20%5Ba%5D%20-%3E%20%5B%5Ba%5D%5D

Comment: @MatrixFrog hoogle by default searches only a few packages, [hayoo](http://holumbus.fh-wedel.de/hayoo/hayoo.html) searches more (I think even all of hackage).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Splitting list into n-tuples](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5819649/splitting-list-into-n-tuples)

Comment: @DanielWagner Hmm.. This one has better answers than that one.

Comment: @AndrewC: I agree, though the title would badly need editing then.

Comment: @AndrewC like it; voted to close both other questions in favour of this one.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

A quick search on [Hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=Int+-%3E+%5Ba%5D+-%3E+%5B%5Ba%5D%5D) showed that there is no such function. On the other hand, it was replied that there is one in the `split` package, called `chunksOf`.

However, you can do it on your own

```
group :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
group _ [] = []
group n l
  | n > 0 = (take n l) : (group n (drop n l))
  | otherwise = error "Negative or zero n"
```

Of course, some parentheses can be removed, I left there here for understanding what the code does:

The base case is simple: whenever the list is empty, simply return the empty list.

The recursive case tests first if `n` is positive. If `n` is `0` or lower we would enter an infinite loop and we don't want that. Then we split the list into two parts using [`take`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:take) and [`drop`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:drop): `take` gives back the first `n` elements while `drop` returns the other ones. Then, we add the first `n` elements to the list obtained by applying our function to the other elements in the original list.

[image]

Comment: Your error message is wrong. `n` is not negative in that case, it is not positive.

Answer (score 38):

This function, among other similar ones, can be found in the popular [split](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/split) package.

```
> import Data.List.Split
> chunksOf 3 [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
```

Comment: `cabal install split`

Answer (score 20):

You can write one yourself, as Mihai pointed out. But I would use the [`splitAt`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Data-List.html#v:splitAt) function since it doesn't require two passes on the input list like the `take`-`drop` combination does:

```
chunks :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
chunks _ [] = []
chunks n xs =
    let (ys, zs) = splitAt n xs
    in  ys : chunks n zs
```

This is a common pattern - generating a list from a seed value (which in this case is your input list) by repeated iteration. This pattern is captured in the [`unfoldr`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Data-List.html#v:unfoldr) function. We can use it with a slightly modified version of `splitAt` (thanks [Will Ness](https://stackoverflow.com/users/849891/will-ness) for the more concise version):

```
chunks n = takeWhile (not . null) . unfoldr (Just . splitAt n)
```

That is, using `unfoldr` we generate chunks of `n` elements while at the same time we shorten the input list by `n` elements, and we generate these chunks until we get the empty list -- at this point the initial input is completely consumed.

Of course, as the others have pointed out, you should use the already existing function from the `split` module. But it's always good to accustom yourself with the list processing functions in the standard Haskell libraries.

Comment: `chunks n xs = takeWhile (not.null) $ unfoldr (Just . splitAt n) xs`. :)

Comment: Thanks ! This is indeed a more elegant implementation.

Comment: If you're new like me and wondering where the `unfoldr` comes from, it is from `Data.List` and is defined as follows. "_The unfoldr function is a `dual' to foldr: while foldr reduces a list to a summary value, unfoldr builds a list from a seed value. The function takes the element and returns Nothing if it is done producing the list or returns Just (a,b), in which case, a is a prepended to the list and b is used as the next element in a recursive call_"

Answer (score 7):

This is ofte called "chunk" and is one of the most frequently mentioned list operations that is not in `base`.  The package [`split`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/split/0.2.1.1/doc/html/Data-List-Split.html) provides such an operation though, copy and pasting the haddock documentation:

```
 > chunksOf 3 ['a'..'z']
 ["abc","def","ghi","jkl","mno","pqr","stu","vwx","yz"]
```

Additionally, against my wishes, hoogle only searches a small set of libraries (those provided with GHC or perhaps HP), but you can explicitly add packages to the search using `+PKG_NAME` - hoogle with `Int -> [a] -> [[a]] +split` gets what you want. Some people use Hayoo for this reason.

Comment: How did you "import" split?  `cabal install split`?  It should just work then, run `ghci` or compile with `ghc` and be sure you used `import Data.List.Split`.  If this is in a cabalized project be sure to add `split` to the build deps.