# How can you combine elements of a list in sets of 3 in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I have a list of strings describing entities like this

```
["prop1", "prop2", "prop3", "prop1", "prop2", "prop3", ... ]
```

Where prop1-3 are the properties of an entity, and the next 3 are the properties of the next entity. I can't figure out a way to group all 3 things together into a list of concatenated strings,

```
[ "prop1\n prop2\n prop3", "prop1\n prop2\n prop3", "prop1\n prop2\n prop3"]
```

or a list of dictionaries,

```
[{
     1: "prop1",
     2: "prop2",
     3: "prop3"
}, {...}]
```

or some such thing.

I'm used to working with loops and am kind of confused when I don't have access to that control flow.

Comment: You aren't trying to generate JSON manually, are you?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it directly using recursion:

```
processIn3s :: (a -> a -> a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
processIn3s f (x:y:z:rest) = f x y z : processIn3s f rest
processIn3s _ _ = []
```

The idea is that **if** the list can be decomposed into

```
x:y:z:rest
```

which can be read as

```
x:(y:(z:rest)))
```

i.e. a list that is the cons (`:`) of `x` and `y:(z:rest)` etc,

**then** we can pass the first three elements `x`, `y` and `z` into a tertiary function `f :: a -> a -> a -> b` that consumes all three elements to come up with the first result; and recurse on the remaining list.

Answer (score 2):

From [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12876438/7208029), you can get them into groups of three using this function:

```hs
groupsOf :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
groupsOf _ [] = []
groupsOf n l
  | n > 0 = (take n l) : (groupsOf n (drop n l))
  | otherwise = error "Negative n"
```

You can then use `Data.List.intercalate` like this:

```hs
map (intercalate "\n ") . groupsOf 3 $ ["prop1", "prop2", "prop3", "prop1", "prop2", "prop3"]
```

This produces:

```hs
["prop1\n prop2\n prop3", "prop1\n prop2\n prop3"]
```

Answer (score 2):

Chai's answer is correct, but instead of writing the function `groupsOf` yourself, you can just use `chunksOf` from `Data.List.Split`.

Comment: But then, how would you intercalate newlines within chunks?

Comment: This should be a comment on Chai's answer, not a separate answer.