# Splitting list into fixed size chunks

Tags: haskell

I am trying to create a Haskell function that takes a list and an integer n and returns the list split into as many sublists of length n as possible. If the length of the list is less than n then the function would return the empty list.

This is what I have, but is there a more simple way to do this is my question?

```
first(a1,_) = a1
second(_,a) = a 

divide :: [a] -> Int -> [[a]]
divide l n = if (length l) < n 
        then []
        else ((first y):(divide (second y) n))
        where y = splitAt n l 

divideTest = [divide ['A'..'Z'] 7 == ["ABCDEFG","HIJKLMN","OPQRSTU"],
          divide [0,3,5,7] 2 == [[0,3],[5,7]]]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Grouping a list into lists of n elements in Haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12876384/grouping-a-list-into-lists-of-n-elements-in-haskell)

Comment: The way your function is using `length`, it will fail on infinite lists. But it is possible to write this in a way that is compatible with infinite lists. See function [chunksOf](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/split-0.2.3.4/docs/Data-List-Split.html#v:chunksOf) for example.

Comment: @MateenUlhaq it's not a _full_ duplicate, `divideTest = [False, True]` with its answers. bit it should be very helpful indeed.