# Haskell -- How to draw lists of characters from a string?

Tags: haskell

How to draw lists of characters from a string?
For example, for a string "abcdefghi", return three strings "adg" "deh" "cfi".
for the first string, it's the 1st, n+1th and n+2th characters from the original string, n is the number of strings to generate.

Comment: What is `n`? How did you get those 3 results? What did you try?

Comment: Do you need to chunk elements? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12876384/grouping-a-list-into-lists-of-n-elements-in-haskell

Comment: @JL0PD It's similar, but not split the characters continuously.

Comment: Maybe it can be done by taking chunks and then `transpose` them later on.

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions:
First: cryptic and short

```hs
drawlist :: Int -> String -> [String]
drawlist n s = [map fst $ filter snd $ zip str [mod c n == i | c<-[0..] ] | i <- [0..(n-1)]]
```

Second: long and maybe clearer

```hs
initlist :: Int -> [String]
initlist 0 = []
initlist n = "":(initlist (n-1))

addtonth :: [String] -> Int -> Char -> [String]
addtonth (x:xc) 1 c = (x++[c]):(addtonth xc 0 c)
addtonth (x:xc) i c = x:(addtonth xc (i-1) c)
addtonth [] i c = []

drawlist' :: Int -> String -> Int -> [String] -> [String]
drawlist' n (x:xs) i s = drawlist' n xs (mod (i+1) n) $ addtonth s (i+1) x
drawlist' n [] i s = s

drawlist :: Int ->  String -> [String]
drawlist n s = drawlist n s 0 $ initlist n
```

Test:

```
Prelude> str = "abcdefghi"
Prelude> drawlist 2 str
["acegi","bdfh"]
Prelude> drawlist 3 str
["adg","beh","cfi"]
Prelude> drawlist 4 str
["aei","bf","cg","dh"]
Prelude> drawlist 5 str
["af","bg","ch","di","e"]
```