# Haskell which function to group list every n such that :: [a] -> Int -> [[a]]

Tags: function, haskell, functional-programming

I'm sure there's a simple function to do this, it should:

```
> groupEvery [1,2,3,4,5,6] 2
[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]
```

I just don't know off hand and hoogle was no help..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Splitting list into n-tuples](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5819649/splitting-list-into-n-tuples)

Comment: If you think this is a duplicate, you might also consider voting to make [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12876384/haskell-operation-on-list) a duplicate.

Comment: @DanielWagner This gives me an idea, I'm pondering going through the haskell tag and every question asking for a function that does X like this, I'm going to add the type sig so SO can be treated like hoogle... maybe...

Comment: @DanielWagner I think we should link to [the second one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12876384/haskell-operation-on-list) because it has better answers. (The top answer of the older one references a function that's not in the current version of the package.)

Comment: "sliding/moving window" or "take n at a time" are terms to google

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is also the [chunksOf](http://lambda.haskell.org/platform/doc/current/packages/split-0.2.2/doc/html/Data-List-Split.html#v:chunksOf) function in the [Data.List.Split](http://lambda.haskell.org/platform/doc/current/packages/split-0.2.2/doc/html/Data-List-Split.html) package, which is part of the Haskell Platform and does exactly what you described.

Answer (score 10):

I don't know of any built-in function for that, but it can be implemented easily:

```
slice :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
slice _ [] = []
slice n xs = hs : slice n ts
  where (hs, ts) = splitAt n xs
```

It repeatedly splits its input to first `n` elements and the rest. Or, using `unfoldr` from `Data.List`:

```
slice n = unfoldr (\xs -> if null xs then Nothing 
                                     else Just (splitAt n xs))
```

---

**Update:** Just for fun I tried to make as short version as possible using standard functions. So far I've got

```
import Data.Functor ((<$))
import Data.List (unfoldr)
import Data.Maybe (listToMaybe)

slice :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
slice n = unfoldr (\xs -> splitAt n xs <$ listToMaybe xs)
```

using [`<$`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-Functor.html#t%3aFunctor) from `Maybe`'s instance of `Functor`. Or slightly shorter but even less comprehensible using `Applicative` for `(->) [a]`:

```
slice n = unfoldr (liftA2 (<$) (splitAt n) listToMaybe)
slice n = unfoldr ((<$) <$> splitAt n <*> listToMaybe)
```

The most incomprehensible version of my attempts was

```
import Control.Monad.Trans
import Control.Monad.Trans.Maybe
slice n = unfoldr (runMaybeT ((MaybeT listToMaybe) >> (lift $ splitAt n)))
```

Comment: Great, it's an unfold I should have recognized that. Unfold being single value->multiple results as opposed to multiple values->single result which is my intuition for fold. I'm surprised there's nothing that does this already, thanks for the simple implementation though!

Comment: @JimmyHoffa This is [`chunksOf`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/split/0.2.2/doc/html/Data-List-Split.html#v:chunksOf) from the `split` package - a very commonly requested function.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson Thanks! I figured there had to be a standard implementation, it would come in handy often enough

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson Thanks, I didn't know about `chunksOf`.

Answer (score 1):

Or, if you like one-liners:

```
slice :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
slice n = takeWhile (not . null) . map fst . drop 1 . iterate (splitAt n . snd) . (\a -> ([],a))
```

Or even:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TupleSections #-}
slice :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
slice n = takeWhile (not . null) . map fst . drop 1 . iterate (splitAt n . snd) . ([],)
```

Comment: I think these are examples of why point-free style is occasionally overrated ;P but thanks. Semantically the action is an unfold, so an unfold is the perfect approach really if you're going to do it yourself